# Problema con el case del switch javascript

Tags: switch

El problema que tengo es que no me entra al case 2 que es para salir, no sé porque, si presiono 2, vuelve a pedirme las opciones  1-operaciones y 2-salir, pero si entra al case 1 que me parece lo extraño, les agradezco si me pueden ayudar, apenas tengo menos de un mes aprendiendo JavaScript. No pude poner todo el código porque dice que es muy largo

```
principal();

function principal(){
do{
var opcion = parseInt(prompt("1-Operaciones\n"+
                "2-Salir\n",0));

switch(opcion){
    
    case 1:
        operaciones();
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
    default: 
    alert("Escoja una opcion válida");
    break;
}
}while(opcion>0);
}
function sumar(){
    var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero1: ",0));
    var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero2: ",0));
    var suma = numero1+numero2;
    alert("La suma es: "+suma); 
}
function restar(){
    var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero1: ",0));
    var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero2: ",0));
    var resta = numero1-numero2;
    alert("La resta es: "+resta); 
}
function dividir(){
    var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero1: ",0));
    var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero2: ",0));
    var divi = numero1/numero2;
    alert("La division es: "+divi); 
}
function producto(){
    var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero1: ",0));
    var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el numero2: ",0));
    var prod = numero1*numero2;
    alert("El producto es: "+prod); 
}
```

Comment: Si quieres salir, cuando se entra en la opción 2, debes eatablecer el valor de la variable `opcion` a cero o cualquier valor negativo. Eso no lo estás haciendo en ninguna parte. Otra forma es escribir la condición del `while` asi: `while (opcion !== 2)`. Saludos

Comment: mmmmm claro es verdad no lo había pensado, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El break te está sacando del switch mas no del do-while, al elegir la opción 2 coloca 'opcion' como una variable igual o menor a 0 para que salga del do-while:

```
do{
var opcion = parseInt(prompt("1-Operaciones\n"+"2-Salir\n",0));
  switch(opcion){
    case 1:
      operaciones();
      break;
    case 2:
      opcion = 0;
      break;
    default: 
      alert("Escoja una opcion válida");
      break;
  }
} while(opcion>0);
```

**EDIT**

Gracias a la sugerencia de @Mateo se me ocurrió crear una función 'isExitOption' que devolverá true si el numero corresponde a la opción salir, puedo usarla para un bucle while del que solo se saldrá cuando se presione la opción 2:

```
const isExitOption = option => option == 2 ? true : false

function principal(){
let opcion = parseInt(prompt("1-Operaciones\n"+"2-Salir\n"));
  while(!isExitOption(opcion)){
    if(opcion == 1) operaciones();
    else alert('Ingrese un numero valido');
    opcion = parseInt(prompt("1-Operaciones\n"+"2-Salir\n"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Una buena práctica es usar funciones. Podrías poner el switch en una función aparte y hacer que devuelva `true` si la opción elegida fue salir y `false` sino. Entonces puedes verificar más fácilmente en el `while` cuándo salir.